# Cutting area from polygon in Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps-api

[image: cut an area from a polygon]

I found [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28826453/how-to-except-area-from-polygon-in-google-maps-api) here.

```js
var map;
function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var triangleCoords1 = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
    new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
    new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.75737),
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262)
  ];
  var triangleCoords2 = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(29, -69),
    new google.maps.LatLng(25, -70),
    new google.maps.LatLng(23, -72),
    new google.maps.LatLng(29, -69)

  ];
  for (var i = 0; i < triangleCoords1.length; i++) {
    bounds.extend(triangleCoords1[i]);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < triangleCoords2.length; i++) {
    bounds.extend(triangleCoords2[i]);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

  bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: [triangleCoords1, triangleCoords2],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

But if I change that to my needs, it will not work.
[image]

```js
var map;
function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var triangleCoords1 = [
     new google.maps.LatLng(51.7339654, 6.4478929),
     new google.maps.LatLng(51.4992925, 6.4666535),
     new google.maps.LatLng(51.5837765, 6.1284897),
     new google.maps.LatLng(51.7339654, 6.4478929)
  ];
  var triangleCoords2 = [
     new google.maps.LatLng(51.6374564, 6.2919939),
     new google.maps.LatLng(51.6474904, 6.3974619),
     new google.maps.LatLng(51.5722125, 6.3693991),
     new google.maps.LatLng(51.6374564, 6.2919939)
 ];
 for (var i = 0; i < triangleCoords1.length; i++) {
    bounds.extend(triangleCoords1[i]);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < triangleCoords2.length; i++) {
    bounds.extend(triangleCoords2[i]);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

  bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: [triangleCoords1, triangleCoords2],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your inner polygon coordinates need to go in the opposite direction  > https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-hole see the commented code. "Note that the points forming the inner path are wound in the opposite direction to those in the outer path, to form the hole."

Answer (score 1):

Thank you "Mapperz" for the hint, that was exactly the solution.

```html
// Note that the points forming the inner path are wound in the
// opposite direction to those in the outer path, to form the hole.
```

The solution is:

```js
triangleCoords2 = triangleCoords2.reverse();
```

[image]

The whole javascript:

```js
var map;
function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var triangleCoords1 = [
     new google.maps.LatLng(51.7339654, 6.4478929),
     new google.maps.LatLng(51.4992925, 6.4666535),
     new google.maps.LatLng(51.5837765, 6.1284897),
     new google.maps.LatLng(51.7339654, 6.4478929)
  ];
  var triangleCoords2 = [
     new google.maps.LatLng(51.6374564, 6.2919939),
     new google.maps.LatLng(51.6474904, 6.3974619),
     new google.maps.LatLng(51.5722125, 6.3693991),
     new google.maps.LatLng(51.6374564, 6.2919939)
 ];
 triangleCoords2 = triangleCoords2.reverse();
 for (var i = 0; i < triangleCoords1.length; i++) {
    bounds.extend(triangleCoords1[i]);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < triangleCoords2.length; i++) {
    bounds.extend(triangleCoords2[i]);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

  bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: [triangleCoords1, triangleCoords2],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```